# Is it possible to share an Application between two or more LoRa Gateways using TTN?

Tags: lora, lorawan

I have a GPS Tracker application which periodically sends Latitude, Longitude, Altitude to a LoRa Gateway.

I am using the [The Things Network](https://thethingsnetwork.org) and sending the data via the **OTAA** method which provides me the Application EUI and Application Key that can be used to program my LoRa device to connect to the Gateway.

But is it possible to connect to a new LoRa Gateway with the same GPS Tracker which for instance, can be placed in some other location of the city?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, the whole point of "The Things Network" (TTN) is that multiple LoRa gateways are used to transfer messages between LoRa radio signals and the Internet based routing.

And these don't even have to be gateways owned by you - by registering your device on TTN you have access to all gateways in the public system, and by making your gateway part of TTN, it is available for all other users' nodes.

Otherwise you'd just have a point-to-point LoRa link or a private LoRaWan, not "The Things Network".